# Reddit API is not working properly

Tags: python

The ups and downs attribute of praw.Objects.Comments class are not working properly. Instead of showing total number of upvotes praw.Objects.Comments.ups is showing the difference between upvotes and downvotes. Is there anyway to access this information?

```
import praw
reddit = praw.Reddit("hackers")
subreddit  = reddit.get_subreddit( "pics" )
top_submissions = subreddit.get_top()
top_submission = next(top_submissions)
first_comment = top_submission.comments[0] 
print(first_comment.ups, first_comment.downs, first_comment.score)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

From this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/announcements/comments/28hjga/reddit_changes_individual_updown_vote_counts_no/), I don't think explicit up and down vote counts are available to the public anymore - Looks like they just make the total score and upvotes the same, and leave downvotes at 0.